# My macbook pro early 2011 wont boot

Tags: macbook-pro

my Macbook pro early 2011 wont boot i tried pretty much anything, i changed the hard drive cleared the Pram and SMC and it still wont work. When i turn it on it has the SLR on but Im greeted with a black screen. The fan and SSD turn on.

Comment: You said, "_When i turn it on it has the SLR on ..._", what is the "SLR"?

Comment: it doesnt work LangLangC

Answer (score 2):

My first thought is the screen--maybe it's booting but the graphics aren't working or the screen isn't working. I have that periodically with an old ThinkPad running Linux. Try connecting to an external monitor and booting.

Another thought: try booting with an external startup disk.

Answer (score 1):

I ran through the usual startup checklist on my macbook pro 17".  None worked.

This recipe did:

Remove battery.

Remove charge cable.

Hold power button down for 10 seconds.  WHILE holding down, reconnect power and hold for an additional 10 seconds.  Booted as I took my finger off.

I don't know why this worked when the usual recipe of remove battery, remove cable, hold power button down 10 seconds, put battery back, put cable back, press power button didn't.

Starting to figure that I need a witch doctor.  "Circle 3 times dorsal, waving a dead battery, and sacrifice a USB corded mouse using a knife made from a sheet of unibody shell, while invoking the Holy name of Steve Jobs..."

Answer (score 0):

I let my computer discharge its self and it seems to do the trick